# how to get list of users from my azure AD using django webapp?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am trying to create a Django web application to integrate with Azure using Microsoft graph.
I am using the provided code on [Python code](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/python) by Microsoft.
Now I want to fetch all the users from my AD. The HTTP request for that is *"GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"*

Please find my code in respective files:-

**graph_helper.py**
[image: graph_helper.py code]

**views.py**
[image: views.py code]

**userslist.html**
[image: userslist.py code]

**urls.py**
[image: urls.py code]

and I am not able to get the desired output. 
[image: Output]

I have created users in my Azure AD successfully yet they are not getting fetched. When I use the above-mentioned HTTP request at [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) it's working.
Kindly help me with the solution. Your time and effort will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: @TonyJu No error is displayed. even the whole code has compiled successfully.

Comment: I am getting this after running the code
[03/Apr/2020 16:08:10] "GET /tutorial/userslist HTTP/1.1" 200 3530

It shows a 200 success code. which means the HTTP request is successfully called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have found the solution for this issue. I realized that I have added the required permission for getting users list but didn't grant the permission. After granting I was able to fetch all users from AD.